# Duda basica con css al usar class

Tags: html, css, css3

Tengo una duda con css que estoy aprendiendo, si pongo la clase por delante de la etiqueta por ejemplo en una list pongo

```
<ul class=ingredients">

.ingredients li {
    list-style: square;
}
```

si lo pongo de esa manera funciona pero si lo pongo al reves no creo que es porque como que selecciona el siguiente elemento que haya en ingredientes ya que luego en un `<p>`
asi

```
<p class="time">Time: 4 minutes</p>

p.time {
  color: blue;
}
```

Luego tambien esta este que no entiendo porque me parece hacer lo mismo que con la lista de arriba

```
<li><h4 class='destination'>Jackson Hole, 
Wyoming</h4></li>

li h4 {
  color: gold;
}
```

asi si se aplica a la primer no se si tengo bien entendido los conceptos y ventajas de usar estos dos metodos, agradeceria algo de ayuda muchas gracias^^

Comment: No veo errores en el CSS ni HTML que has puesto. ¿A qué te refieres con "al revés"? Pon la estructura concreta del HTML y CSS en el que no se muestran los estilos/estructura deseados.

Comment: es una duda de concepto y usos. al reves me refiero por la clase y etiqueta al ponerlo en el selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no hay mejor maestro que una prueba

veamos:

```css
/* esto seleccionara a los hijos li de la clase ingrendients
o lo que es igual a los li que sean hijos de ingredients
*/
.ingredients li {
     color:green;
}

/* pegado: seleccionara p que contenga la clase time */
p.time {
  color: blue;
}


/* esto seleccionara al elemento h4 que sean hijos de li */
li h4 {
  color: gold;
}

/* separado: como ves la variante indica que debe ser hijo de h4 con clase time */
h4 .time {
  color: orange;
}

/* esto seleccionara la clase par que sea hija de ul
pero ojo esta dentro de un li que omite
*/

ul .par {
  color: silver;
}

/* esto seleccionara la clase par que sea hija de ul
con el > obligamos a que sea hijo directo
*/

ul  > .par {
  color: purple;
}

/* esto seleccionara  solo los hijos de li que sean h2 y h3
con coma podemos especificarlo para varios elementos
*/

li h3, li h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ingredients">
  <li>hola</li>
  <li><p class="time">Time: 4 minutes</p></li>
  <li><h4 class='destination'>Jackson Hole, Wyoming</h4></li>
  <li><h4 class="time"><span class="time">Time: 5 minutes</span></h4></li>
  <li><p class="par">Time: 6 minutes</p></li>
  <p class="par">Time: 7 minutes</p>
  <li><h3 >Jackson Hole, Wyoming</h3></li>
  <li><h2>Jackson Hole, Wyoming</h2></li>
  <!-- no es hijo de li -->
  <h2>Jackson Hole, Wyoming</h2>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola @FranyXD creo que tienes el concepto mal entendido. Haber si tienes el siguiente código

```
<ul class=ingredients">
.ingredients li {
    list-style: square;
}
```

Esto lo que les estas diciendo es lo siguiente que la clase **ingredients** y sus hijos `li` tengan dicho estilo.

En cambio con el otro código le estas diciendo lo siguiente:

```
<p class="time">Time: 4 minutes</p>
p.time {
  color: blue;
}
```

Que todas las etiquetas `p` de tu html que contengan la clase **time** tengan dicho estilo.

Espero que ahora entiendas mejor los conceptos.

Comment: Vale ya entiendo, actualice mi pregunta añadiendo otro metodo mas que me choca con el primero , cual es la diferencia? no hacen cosas parecidas?